# The urls of images that are in my liferay theme are not become invalid when I change protlet

Tags: url, tomcat, liferay, portlet, liferay-theme

I have created a liferay theme where I placed some images to the footer.

I also have several pages and each page is a portlet.

When I first visit the home page after server starts up, the the URLs are working like a charm.

The problem is that whenever I visit another page/portlet the images disappear and the firefox console inform me about this:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http//localhost/web/18/...footerLgo.png

This means that something is wrong with the tomcat URL and the URL I have declared.

Where should I put my images in order to be displayed no matter where I navigate to?

Maybe in a tomcat folder, but where? And if so, what would be the URL that I should declare?

Comment: It seems that you have changed the port from default 8080 to 80, is it correct?

Comment: No my port is 8080. I think that maybe this is caused due to  redirection.

Comment: The URL by NetworkError is 'http//localhost/web/18/...footerLgo.png' - that is port 80. Have you change the liferay properties?